# How do I get rid of spam SMSs that do not want to delete?

Tags: sms, spam

I get these spam SMSs on my Sony Xperia. I try to delete them, but I can't. I select the SMS to delete, then confirm to delete. It takes ages and then my phone tells me the message is deleted, but it is not. It is still there!

Answer (score 0):

Go on setting and open application section . Now go to system apps and search message application . Open it and click clear data and also clear catch . By doing this your problem will be solved

Comment: That will probably unrecoverably delete all messages, yes. The OP may want to use a backup tool first!

Comment: I did go to Settings>>Apps>>ALL>>Messaging and clicked on Clear Data. It also cleared the Cache simultaneously. I went back to Messaging and found a screen saying GET STARTED. I clicked on it and all my messages were there. Tried to delete the unwanted ones, but I still get the same result. Went back to Settings to find data all the data was back again. Did I go to the wrong place in Settings? System apps are not separately listed on my phone.